# Accessing the value of a variable while model is still optimizing?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I was wondering whether in `JuMP` it's possible to be aware of the value of variables while the model is still running??  I mean, suppose we have a set of binary variables `x(i,j)  i,j in [1,2,..5]`. Is there any possiblity to know which variable get the value of one. for example,  and as soons as model assigns`x(1,2) =1` is it possible to know? Or we have to wait untill the model is entirely done??

Comment: You can basically do something like this through callbacks (supported mostly by commercial solvers) and by the corresponding libraries from the JuMP ecosystem. Start by having a look at https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_cb_s.html and then maybe extend your question and we will surely answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

JuMP supports three solver-independent callbacks:

- Lazy constraints
- User cuts
- Heuristic callbacks

Docs:

- https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/callbacks/
- https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/linear/callbacks/

You can also write a solver-dependent callback for solvers like Gurobi. Check the README of each solver.

- https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl#callbacks

Here's the example:

```
using JuMP, Gurobi, Test

model = direct_model(Gurobi.Optimizer())
@variable(model, 0 <= x <= 2.5, Int)
@variable(model, 0 <= y <= 2.5, Int)
@objective(model, Max, y)
cb_calls = Cint[]
function my_callback_function(cb_data, cb_where::Cint)
    # You can reference variables outside the function as normal
    push!(cb_calls, cb_where)
    # You can select where the callback is run
    if cb_where != GRB_CB_MIPSOL && cb_where != GRB_CB_MIPNODE
        return
    end
    # You can query a callback attribute using GRBcbget
    if cb_where == GRB_CB_MIPNODE
        resultP = Ref{Cint}()
        GRBcbget(cb_data, cb_where, GRB_CB_MIPNODE_STATUS, resultP)
        if resultP[] != GRB_OPTIMAL
            return  # Solution is something other than optimal.
        end
    end
    # Before querying `callback_value`, you must call:
    Gurobi.load_callback_variable_primal(cb_data, cb_where)
    x_val = callback_value(cb_data, x)
    y_val = callback_value(cb_data, y)
    # You can submit solver-independent MathOptInterface attributes such as
    # lazy constraints, user-cuts, and heuristic solutions.
    if y_val - x_val > 1 + 1e-6
        con = @build_constraint(y - x <= 1)
        MOI.submit(model, MOI.LazyConstraint(cb_data), con)
    elseif y_val + x_val > 3 + 1e-6
        con = @build_constraint(y + x <= 3)
        MOI.submit(model, MOI.LazyConstraint(cb_data), con)
    end
    if rand() < 0.1
        # You can terminate the callback as follows:
        GRBterminate(backend(model))
    end
    return
end
# You _must_ set this parameter if using lazy constraints.
MOI.set(model, MOI.RawOptimizerAttribute("LazyConstraints"), 1)
MOI.set(model, Gurobi.CallbackFunction(), my_callback_function)
optimize!(model)
@test termination_status(model) == MOI.OPTIMAL
@test primal_status(model) == MOI.FEASIBLE_POINT
@test value(x) == 1
@test value(y) == 2
```